# Imagick multiple pages PDF to JPG fatal error

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

**What does not work:**

- Converting filename-multiple-pages.pdf[0] PDF file to JPG
- Converting filename-multiple-pages.pdf PDF file to JPG

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'Postscript delegate failed `/path/to/filename-multiple-pages.pdf': No
>   such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/664' in ...

When I try this with a sollution found on the webs with fopen and then using readImageFile of the fopen handle:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'Postscript delegate failed `/tmp/magick-rGGsdy9f': No such file or
>   directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/664'

**What does work:**

- Converting filename-multiple-pages.pdf[1] PDF file to JPG (the second page)
- Converting filename-single-page.pdf PDF to JPG [/list]

**The used PHP codes:**

```
<?php

  // this does work for a single page file
  // it does NOT work for multiple page file
  // it does NOT work when using pdffile.pdf[0]
  // it DOES work when using pdffile.pdf[1]

  $filename = '/path/to/pdffile.pdf';  
  $im = new Imagick();
  $im->readImage($filename);
  $im = $im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
  $im->scaleImage(150, 150, true);
  $im->writeImage('/path/to/image/pdffile.jpg');
?>


<?php
  // i used alternative code which gave me the second /tmp/ dir error (see above)

  $filename = '/path/to/pdffile.pdf';    
  $pdf_handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
  $doc_preview = new Imagick();
  $doc_preview->setResolution(150,150);
  $doc_preview->readImageFile($pdf_handle);
  $doc_preview->setIteratorIndex(0);
  $doc_preview->setImageFormat('jpeg');
  $doc_preview->writeImage('/path/to/image/pdffile.jpg');
  $doc_preview->clear();
  $doc_preview->destroy();

?>
```

**Installed modules by hosting provider**

- ImageMagick v6.7.2.7-5
- Ghostscript 8.70

Does anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? and PHP can reat it? You can test if(is_file( '/path/to/pdffile.pdf')) echo 'OK'; else echo ' NOT FILE';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that the hosting provider didn't install recent versions. After a few days of testing and debugging they managed to install the latest versions and it all works now. The code in my post is good and can be used by others :).